# Trouble with error code: "Error: Fill argument neither colors nor valid variable name(s)"

Tags: r, tmap

I am trying to make a map with tmap and when I try to view it, this error code comes up:

Error: Fill argument neither colors nor valid variable name(s)

Here is my code.

```r
tm1=tm_shape(myshptime1)+
  tm_polygons("zeta.x",style="pretty",
              palette="PuOr", title="Spatial Residual \n Relative Risk ")+
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE)

tm1
```

I've tried adding a fill argument, I've tried adding other types of arguments, and I get the same error. I also tried switching from "plot" to "view" to display the map under a different mode and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with your shapefile, which we do not have access to. As your problem is not quite reproducible it will be difficult to help you.

Consider the following example, which uses your exact code but with the shapefile of North Carolina (it ships with the {sf} package, so it is widely available) in place of your `myshptime1` object; I have also swapped your "zeta.x" for "AREA", as there is no `zeta.x` variable in the {sf} shapefile.

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)

shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) # included with sf package


tm1 = tm_shape(shape)+
  tm_polygons("AREA",style="pretty",
              palette="PuOr", title="Spatial Residual \n Relative Risk ")+
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE)

tm1
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, I thought that could be the issue but the map creation works from one command to the next. There doesn't seem to be a pattern to it.